# Using decode for parameter positioning cases

Tags: sql, informatica-powercenter

I have a table which contains a list of 13 digit numbers.

I want to use informatica to break these numbers down and separate them based on cases.

For example, I have the number 1196804120316.
For the first case, I wish to only take the two digits after the 68. In our example, I extract the number 04 and store it in a column.

The SQL Code for it is:

```
CASE WHEN ODS_CI_RPT.ADMIN.REGEXP_LIKE(DEC_REGISTRN_NBR,'^(19|20)?[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{5,6}$') 
THEN
ODS_CI_RPT.ADMIN.REGEXP_REPLACE(DEC_REGISTRN_NBR,'.*-([0-9]{2})-.*','\1',1,1)
ELSE '05'
END
AS 
STATE_CODE
```

The next case is to take the number after 19 and store it. In this case the 68.
The SQL is:

```
CASE WHEN  ODS_CI_RPT.ADMIN.REGEXP_LIKE(DEC_REGISTRN_NBR,'^(19|20)?[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{5,6}$') THEN
 ODS_CI_RPT.ADMIN.REGEXP_REPLACE(DEC_REGISTRN_NBR,'^([0-9]{2,4})-.*','\1',1,1)
 ELSE ODS_CI_RPT.ADMIN.REGEXP_REPLACE(DEC_REGISTRN_NBR,'^([0-9]{4})-.*','\1',1,1)
 END
 AS 
 D_BIRTH_YEAR,
```

How would I implement this using decode in informatica?

Comment: The regular expressions seem to be trying to match numbers with hyphen in them. But the number you are trying to match does not have hyphen '-' in it?

Comment: The number `1196804120316` could not possibly match the regex `^(19|20)?[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{5,6}$`

Comment: I'm going to take a punt and say you want to split the string out into multiple columns using SUBSTR() in the expression of each and then apply your logic onto the smaller fields

Comment: You are correct Daniel, this is how it is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this was to use SUBSTR() in an expression. After importing the source from the table, I used:

```
SUBSTR(COLUMN_NAME,6,2)
```

To tell Informatica which position of the string I wanted broken down. Once it was broken down, the expression would capture it into a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try:

```
WITH
input(literal) AS (
SELECT '1196804120316'
)
SELECT 
  -- use below in PowerCenter
  MONTH(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(literal,2),'YYYYMMDDHHMI')) 
  -- use above in PowerCenter
  AS the_month
FROM input;

the_month
        4
```

Power Center offers all functions of Oracle. So just use the formula I show above .....